# How do I save the selected option in the combobox

Tags: inno-setup

I need help . I have in my script the ability to record and save what you write in the box . How do I save the selected option in the combobox?

line of code :
EditIndex1 : InputPage.Add = ( ' Name ' , False ) ;
InputPage.Values ​​[ EditIndex1 ] : = GetPreviousData ( ' Name' , '') ;

and :
SetPreviousData ( PreviousDataKey , ' Name ' , InputPage.Values ​​[ 0 ] ) ;

Thank you .

Comment: Combo box has either the `Text` property which gives you the string value which the user can see in the combo box' edit, or `ItemIndex` which gives you the selected item index (but which you cannot use when the combo box is in the style which allows the user type a text in the combo box).

Comment: Hi, TLama, As it is written to the selected component , thought it would be possible to store the selected value of a combobox ...

is there another way ? and if ListBox?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand. I meant that instead of `InputPage.Values​[0]` you can pass something like `YourComboBoxObject.Text` to the `SetPreviousData` function. You didn't say anything about a list box in your question.

Comment: Thanks so much TLama. Helped a lot.